# Bash script : How to export file name as header to csv

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing

I have multiple .txt files in my folder " Subj1 " arranged in following format

```
  regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt
  regional_vol_GM_atlas1_prop.txt
  ....
  regional_vol_GM_atlas152.txt
```

each file consists of data in following format

```
667869 667869
580083 580083
316133 316133
11398.1 11398.1
```

i would like to export the data along with associated file name in text file to csv  file.

I have written a code for that

```
#!/bin/bash

for x in regional_vol*.txt; do

   /bin/echo -n -e "$x\t"

done

paste regional_vol*.txt >> final_table.csv
```

which pastes the data in each file into csv file,the sample output image looks like this ,

[image: Output image]

but in the output i would like to obtain associated file name as a header for the data  how could i change my code to obtain such output ?

This is the sample example of output i expect

[image: Sample output]

Comment: I don't understand your script. In the loop, you simply `echo` the filenames to `STDOUT` with a tab at the end, it really doesn't do anything! The `paste` command should be enough.

Comment: @maulinglawns : exactly paste should be enough to copy the data in text file and paste it in CSV, but i would like to use the file name of each file as a header, right now it only echos file names how can i change it ?

Comment: By using [redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) perhaps?

Comment: @maulinglawns , tried with redirection, none of it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple but not elegant solution will be add the file name in the first line of each file:

```
for x in $(ls regional_vol*.txt | sort -n); do
   echo ${x} > tmp-${x}
   cat ${x} >> tmp-${x}
done

paste tmp-regional_vol*.txt > final_table.csv
rm tmp-regional_vol*.txt
```

Comment: It fails unfortunately, i could see complete mismatch between headers and associated data in files

Comment: It works fine here, can you send a screenshot or the final_table.csv?

Comment: Hello ,unfortunately, i dont have enough points to send you that

Comment: This is the screen shot  http://imgur.com/YiUnoEY

Comment: I have sent you a screen shot

Comment: Thanks its working , but i have only one problem, I need an output file that should be ascending order , this output is not so accurate to  what i expect , i am presenting a screen shot http://imgur.com/WOOhJXk

Comment: I updated the script, you don't specified the sort method so I'm using the default one, you can see `sort --help` for detail. Now the original files will not be overwritten anymore

Comment: The problem is ,its still giving me same output, its not sorted in ascending order

Comment: just updated, try this one.

Comment: I want files to be on ascending order, but data is getting rearranged in ascending order , check this image  http://imgur.com/dfmnxju

Comment: The first column should be regional_vol_GM_atlas1 and corresponding values of the file, similarly with second column

Comment: You need to best specify your problem! One last update!

Comment: If you see http://imgur.com/dfmnxju,the first row starts with regional_vol_GM_atlas100.txt and corresponding values of that files are updated, what i need is a csv file starting with regional_vol_GM_atlas1.txt and corresponding values updated,next column should be regional_vol_GM_atlas2.txt and its corresponding values

Comment: Thanks, i solved it, only problem is its getting overwritten,how to avoid it ?

Comment: It isn't getting overwritten

Comment: actually i was using :  sed -i "1s/^/${x}\n/" ${x}

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a simple redirection to the `echo` command, and most likely another `echo` to print a newline. Something like this:

```
files="regional_vol*.txt"
dst=final_table.csv
# remove the hash sign here to truncate the destination before writing
# > $dst    
for x in $files; do
   /bin/echo -n -e "$x\t" >> $dst
done
echo >> $dst
paste $files >> $dst
```

or with `printf` instead of the loop:

```
printf "%s\t" $files >> $dst
echo >> $dst
paste $files >> $dst
```

Both of those will print an extra tab at the end of the header line, but that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: it fails again, i need the header name on top of associated data, i have updated my question again please check

Comment: I have updated my question again ,the out from your code looks like this http://imgur.com/NDiMRA1

Answer (score 0):

(*I am assuming that you have rotated the file, since each file is a column in the pictures.*)

In your script, each file is added as a row in the CSV.  Each row in the CSV should be a row in the spreadsheet.

Use SED and AWK to manipulate the file contents and build a string, "filename,field1,field2,field3,...".  Echo that string to append to your CSV.

Then do the same rotation you've done on the pictured spreadsheet when you open it.  Or keep it in the usual, "each row is an entry", format.  Actually this is recommended, because the filename should be a field, not a header.  In other words, the field with the header name of filename should contain the filename for each entry in your CSV.